# Extending Polynomial Class with math operations

Tags: python, object-oriented, mathematics

## Background

After seeing a random coding interview question "write a program that can take the derivative of a polynomial", I decided to solve the problem using an OOP approach in Python. Then, I wanted to practice more, so built out a "fully" functioning Polynomial class. I am looking both for ways to improve my code and possible ways to expand this project. So far it can:

- compute the value of a given Polynomial for any given float
- perform field operations like addition, subtraction, & scalar multiplication
- perform standard calculus operations like differentiation and integration
- displays instances in a more aesthetic format:

  ```
  >>> print(Poly(-7, 0, 0, 12, 12, -2, 0))

  -7.0x⁶ + 12.0x³ + 12.0x² - 2.0x
  ```

Below is the main file and supporting script for the `__str__` method

## Polynomial.py (main)

```
from FormattingFuncs import mathformat


class Poly:
    """
    Polynomial(*coeffs) -> Polynomial

    Supports:
    - Computing real-valued polynomials for any given float/int
    - Field operations: can add, subtract, & scalar multiply polynomials
    - Calculus opeartions: can differentatiate & integrate polynomials
    """

    def __init__(self, *coeffs):
        """
        Creates a new Polynomial object by passing in floats/ints
        Passed in args correspond to coefficients in decreasing degree order
        """
        try:
            if coeffs[0] == 0 and len(coeffs) > 1:
                raise ValueError('First argument of non-constant Polynomial must be non-zero')

            self.coeffs = coeffs
            # self.coeffs = {degree: coeff for degree, coeff in enumerate(reversed(coeffs))}
            self.degree = len(coeffs) - 1
            self.isConst = (len(coeffs) == 1)  # P(x) = c
            self.isLinear = (len(coeffs) == 2)  # P(x) = ax + b

        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError(f'Oops! {type(self).__name__} requires atleast 1 float/int arg')

    def value(self, x):
        """Computes P(x=float/int)"""
        # Makes finding y-intercept a constant time process, since y-int := P(0) = const term
        if x == 0:
            val = self.coeffs[-1]
        else:
            val = sum(self.coeffs[i] * (x ** (self.degree - i)) for i in range(self.degree + 1))

        return val

    def differentiate(self):
        """Computes differentiated Polynomial object: dP/dx"""
        if self.isConst:
            coeffs = (0,)
        else:
            coeffs = (self.coeffs[i] * (self.degree - i) for i in range(self.degree))

        return Poly(*coeffs)

    def integrate(self, const=0):
        """Computes integrated Polynomial object given some integrating constant: ∫P(x)dx + c"""
        coeffs = [self.coeffs[i] / (self.degree + 1 - i) for i in range(self.degree + 1)]
        coeffs.append(const)

        return Poly(*coeffs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        Polynomial(*coeffs1) + Polynomial(*coeffs2) -> Polynomial(*coeffs3)
        Polynomial(*coeffs4) + float/int -> Polynomial(*coeffs5)
        """
        try:
            # Prepends smaller degree polynomial with leading 0's
            diff = self.degree - other.degree
            leadingZeros = tuple(0 for _ in range(abs(diff)))

            if diff > 0:
                p1coeffs = self.coeffs
                p2coeffs = leadingZeros + other.coeffs
            else:
                p1coeffs = leadingZeros + self.coeffs
                p2coeffs = other.coeffs

            sumcoeffs = [sum(c) for c in zip(p1coeffs, p2coeffs)]

            # Finds index of first non-zero term
            leadingindex = -1
            for c in sumcoeffs:
                leadingindex += 1
                if c is not 0: break

            sumcoeffs = sumcoeffs[leadingindex:]

            return Poly(*sumcoeffs)

        # Handles case when adding a scalar -> shifts polynomial vertically
        except AttributeError:
            coeffs = list(self.coeffs)
            coeffs[-1] += other

            return Poly(*coeffs)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        """
        Polynomial(*coeffs1) + Polynomial(*coeffs2) -> Polynomial(*coeffs3)
        float/int + Polynomial(*coeffs4) -> Polynomial(*coeffs5)
        """
        return self + other

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        """Polynomial(coeffs=tuple) * float/int -> Polynomial(coeffs=tuple2)"""
        if not isinstance(scalar, (float, int)):
            raise TypeError(f"'{type(scalar).__name__}' object cannot be multiplied"
                            f" - only supports scalar (float/int) multiplication")
        elif scalar == 0:
            coeffs = (0,)
        else:
            coeffs = (coeff * scalar for coeff in self.coeffs)

        return Poly(*coeffs)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        """float/int * Polynomial(coeffs=tuple) -> Polynomial(coeffs=tuple2)"""
        return self * other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """
        Polynomial(*coeffs1) - Polynomial(*coeffs2) -> Polynomial(*coeffs3)
        Polynomial(*coeffs4) - float/int -> Polynomial(*coeffs5)
        """
        return self + (-1 * other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        """
        Polynomial(*coeffs1) - Polynomial(*coeffs2) -> Polynomial(*coeffs3)
        float/int - Polynomial(*coeffs4) -> Polynomial(*coeffs5)
        """
        return other + (-1 * self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}{self.coeffs}'

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Displays 'mathematical' representation of polynomial:
        i.e. Polynomial(-1, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 1) ->  -x⁶ - 2x² + 1
        """
        poly = ''.join(mathformat(k, self.coeffs) for k in range(self.degree + 1))

        return poly
```

## FormattingFuncs.py

```
# File includes 3 support functions for Poly.__str__ method


def mathformat(term, coeffs):
    """Returns formatted term of Polynomial according to coefficient's parity and value"""
    # Booleans used for control flow to exhaust all cases
    isLeadingTerm = (term == 0)
    isConstTerm = (term == len(coeffs) - 1)

    # Handles case where polynomial is constant
    if isLeadingTerm and isConstTerm: return str(coeffs[0])

    c = float(coeffs[term])

    # Handles formatting the highest order term's coefficient
    if c == 1:
        leadingstr = ''
    elif c == -1:
        leadingstr = '-'
    else:
        leadingstr = f'{c:.03}'

    # Formats coefficient accordingly; superscripts degree unless it's the linear term
    coeff = leadingstr if isLeadingTerm else formatcoeff(term, coeffs)
    degree = f'{superscript(len(coeffs) - 1 - term)}'
    formattedterm = f'{coeff}x' + degree * (degree != '¹')

    polyformat = formatcoeff(term, coeffs) if (isConstTerm or c == 0) else formattedterm

    return polyformat


def formatcoeff(term, coeffs):
    """Transforms coefficient into appropriate str"""
    c = float(coeffs[term])

    isConstTerm = (term == len(coeffs) - 1)
    isUnitary = (abs(c) == 1)  # checks if c = 1 or -1

    coeff = '' if (isUnitary and not isConstTerm) else abs(c)

    if c > 0:
        formatted = f' + {coeff:.03}'
    elif c < 0:
        formatted = f' - {coeff:.03}'
    else:
        formatted = ''

    return formatted


def superscript(value, reverse=False):
    """
    Returns a str with any numbers superscripted: H2SO4 -> H²SO⁴
    Change reverse param to 'True' to subscript: H2SO4 -> H₂SO₄
    """
    digits = ('⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉')[reverse]
    transtable = str.maketrans("0123456789", digits)
    formatted = str(value).translate(transtable)

    return formatted
```

Comment: Numpy also has a polynomial class, located at numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py. You may want to have a look at that for further inspiration or see how they approached it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It looks strange that you all right with constant zero polynomial (e.g. `differentiate` may produce one), yet you don't allow to construct one explicitly.
- `value` can benefit from a Horner schedule, both in time complexity and precision. Along the same line, case `x == 0` seems like a premature optimization.
- You seem to assume that `AttributeError` in `__add__` implies that `other` is of a numeric type. Unfortunately it only means that `other` doesn't have `coeffs`, and you may end up with very strangely looking `coeffs[-1]`.